# How to make a numpy array of values into a callable function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numeric

Is it possible to use `scipy.optimize` schemes to minimize a function given purely numerically and not by an expression?

Specifically, a program that solves partial differential equations returns an array whose entries are the values of a solution to the equation on the unit square in the plane. I would like to use that function in a minimization problem. Now all the `scipy` minimizers seem to work well for the functions of type

```
    def function(x):
        return expression(x)
```

but I can't figure out how to use them in this general situation. To focus on a specific problem suppose we have the following data

```
    x = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
    y = solution_matrix_row_n
```

where the matrix is purely numerical of shape `(100,100)`, with no explicit dependence on `x`. For example the 11th row of a solution to some Poisson equation with mixed boundary conditions plotted against `x` looks something like that:

[image: graph]

How do I make a function

```
    x -> y
```

that would be accepted by one of the `scipy.optimize` schemes?

Comment: errr.. exactly as you have oulined in your question, `return np.random.randn(100) + 2*x`

Comment: @DrBwts Does not work. I edited the question so there is no explicit dependence on `x` whatsoever.
 I've just put `def function(x): return y` and after running `scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar(function)` I got `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'`.

Comment: edit your question including all the code you have tried, it will be easier to see what you mean.

Comment: `scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar` says the function must take a scalar input (i.e. one numeric value), and return a scalar.  The minimize code will call this function repeatedly with a value (selected from some range), expecting one value back, which it tries to minimize.  The function doesn't actually have to use the value of `x`, but if it doesn't the calculation is pointless - what's the minimum of a 'constant' or 'random' function?

Comment: There are other `minimize` functions, some of which take an array `x`.  But I think all require that `x` to be 1d (but a 2d array is easily reshaped0.  And all require a single return value.  Minimizing an array value is theoretically difficult if not impossible (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency)

Comment: @hpaulj I agree - in case of random array one might as well brute force it. But I strongly disagree, that looking for a minimum when no explicit dependence on `x` is given is pointless. Here the matrix comes from a solution to pde, so that it will implicitly dependent on `x` and be quite regular, so using e.g. gradient descent (approximated with finite differences) should in theory save a lot of resources. I just don't see how to use `scipy` tools for that.

Comment: I still don't see how the objective function, the cost, depends on a value  that `minimize` can vary. What does this have to do with matrix `x`?